# AccessibilityManager alternative in flutter

Tags: android, swift, flutter, android-studio, dart

Is there an alternative like AccessibilityManager which is in android studio, in flutter? This is for the purpose of monitoring activity on the device like in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has the [devtools](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/overview) that helps you gain insight into your app's performance, memory usage etc. This works in the browser